# RegexOptions.IgnoreCase not replacing

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I made a console application to test a regular expression replace:

```
    string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><orders><order>";
    xml = Regex.Replace(xml, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(xml);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

But I get the same output as my input, could anyone of you help me?:)
What i want is that the first part of the string gets deleted and only "" is returned

Comment: The 2nd argument to `Regex.Replace` is a regex. I.e. `<?` is interpreted as an optional "`<`" etc.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your regex contains meta-characters. For example, `<?` means "an optional `<`", not "a `<` followed by a `?`".

You need to escape the meta-characters before calling `Replace`:

```
    xml = Regex.Replace(
        xml
    ,   Regex.Escape("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>")
    ,   ""
    ,   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the `?`s, so you're still looking for an optional `<` at the beginning of the string ;)

Comment: @VitorM.Barbosa `Regex.Escape` escapes the entire string.

Comment: you're right, I looked right at the string and missed the `Regex.Escape`.

Answer (score 1):

Your Replace should look like this:

```
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"<\?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""\?>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I replaced the ? with \? and I also changed the string notation to the alternative format that is very usefull for Regex.